# AngularJs http request concats my data into a JSON key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, xmlhttprequest, angularjs-http

Sometimes a behavior is so bizarre that I don't even know how to begin to google it. I'm fairly new at Angular, and I am trying to send POST data to my node server from the client. Here is the controller on the client side:

```
var app = angular.module("groomer", []);
app.controller("gCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $scope.send = function() {
        $http({
            method : "POST",
            url : "/gUpdate",
            data: {
                gName:$scope.gName,
                gPhone:$scope.gPhone,
                gWebsite:$scope.gWebsite,
                gEmail:$scope.gEmail,
                gCustAcct:$scope.gCustAcct,
                gAddress:$scope.gAddress,
                gNotes:$scope.gNotes
            }
        }).then(function success(response) {
            alert(console.log('Success!'));
        }, function error(response) {
            alert(console.log('Booooooo'));
        });
    };
});
```

What I naively imagine ought to show up at the server is:

```
    req.body = {
        gName:'a', 
        gPhone:'b', 
        gWebsite:'c', 
        gEmail:'d', 
        gCustAcct:'e', 
        gAddress:'f', 
        gNotes:'g'
    }
```

But things get weird. What actually shows up at the server as the request body is:

```
{"{\"gName\":\"a\",\"gPhone\":\"b\",\"gWebsite\":\"c\",\"gEmail\":\"d\",\"gCustAcct\":\"e\",\"gAddress\":\"f\",\"gNotes\":\"g\"}":""}
```

In case it takes you a second to see what's happening here, that's all of my JSON keys and data in an object, double-quoted, escaped, concatenated as a string, and passed to the server inside an object as a JSON key corresponding to an empty value.

```
//so
var lifeMakesSense = {gName:'a',gPhone:'b',gWebsite:'c',gEmail:'d',gCustAcct:'e',gAddress:'f',gNotes:'g'}
//becomes
var waitNo = "{\"gName\":\"a\",\"gPhone\":\"b\",\"gWebsite\":\"c\",\"gEmail\":\"d\",\"gCustAcct\":\"e\",\"gAddress\":\"f\",\"gNotes\":\"g\"}"
//then
var whatEven = {waitNo:""} // nailed it
```

Thoughts?

Comment: If you want your data as JSON, then why are you sending it using **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** content type. It should be **application/json** for JSON request.

Comment: @NisheshPratap To my understanding, **application/json** is the default which Angular uses for http encoding. I changed the encoding because I was receiving an empty request body on the server side.

Comment: you are correct, I asked that question because I saw you are changing it to **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**.

Comment: Should the **application/json** encoding work with Node? I'm using the **body-parser** module as a middleware: _const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));_ which has served me well in other apps that just used plain old AJAX or JQuery.